# iPhone says "The Apple Id you entered Couldn't be found or was incorrect. Please try again."

Tags: iphone, itunes, accounts, password

All of a sudden my iPhone 4 (iOS4.0.2) can no longer download apps. It says:

> The Apple Id you entered Couldn't be found or was incorrect. Please try again.

I know for certain that the password is entered correctly. I have only 1 iTunes ID. I downloaded an app successfully this morning, over 3G. But now I consistently get this message when I try to download any app! I'm still on 3G with adequate signal strength.

I've quit all running apps, I've restarted (twice) and even a hard reset. But still I get this message. I've also noticed that the **battery level is falling rapidly** (1% every 2 min's) despite no other running apps/wifi/Bluetooth, so it must be doing some heavy 3G traffic.

**What's up? How can I solve this?** Preferably *without involving my PC at home* because I will be travelling for the next few days...

My exact steps:

- tap on App Store
- find any (free) app, tap on `Install`. Itunes closes, I see a white placeholder app icon labeled `Waiting...`, and I'm asked my iTunes password.
- I enter the correct password and tap `OK`.
- The white placeholder icon is still `Waiting...` for a *long* time.
- After ~5min's the correct app icon is show, but still labeled `Waiting...`.
- After additionally ~5min's there's a new popup with the text `The Apple Id you entered Couldn't be found or was incorrect. Please try again.` and buttons `Cancel` and `Retry`.

Note: I've seen entries like [this one](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11381950) but they are based on working on a Macintosh. I'm at work so I hope for a mobile solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might have been some kind of outage in the App Store,** because it works now, following the exact same steps with the exact same conditions (location, network, etc.).